# plus button under listview

Tags: qt, listview, button, qml

I can create "+" (plus) button under all listview items.
This button will add a new item.

I can place it under all exsisting items. But ideály as a part as list.Because of scrolling, scrollbars and other standard listview functions. If listview will be not fill all available page size, scrolls will be ended in the middle of the screan etc...

I tested counting onpaint signal or something like this, but have no success. Because signal for one row goint more than one times, counting is mismatched and button is one time in seccond row, one time below third, sometimes is missing etc...

Example image:

[image]

Source code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Page {
title: qsTr("Page 1")
anchors.fill: parent
focus: true
property int myIndex: 0

function setVisibility()
{
    if(myModel.rowCount()*3 === myIndex)
    {
        myIndex = 0
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        myIndex = myIndex + 1
        return false
    }
}


/*
 *
 *
 * ListView Component
 *
 *
 */
ListView
{
    id: listView1
    model: myModel
    currentIndex: 0
    //property int actualHeight
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true
    //spacing: 40

    highlightMoveDuration: 1
    highlightMoveVelocity: 1
    highlightResizeDuration: 0.0
    highlight: Rectangle
    {
        color: "#2e6377"
        opacity: 0.3
    }

    delegate: hDelegate


}


/*
 *
 *
 * ListViewItem Component
 *
 *
 */
Component
{
    id: hDelegate
    Item
    {
        width: parent.width
        height: taskInfo.implicitHeight
        property variant mainData: model
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:
            {
                listView1.currentIndex = index
                gIdd = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_idd
                gSubject = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_subject
                gBody = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_body
                listView1.currentIndex = index
            }
            onDoubleClicked:
            {
                listView1.currentIndex = index
                stackView.push("page3.qml")
            }
            onPressAndHold:
            {
                listView1.currentIndex = index
                stackView.push("page3.qml")
            }
            hoverEnabled: true
        }


        Row
        {
            id: taskInfo
            spacing: 5
            Rectangle
            {
                id: dificultStatus
                height: taskColumn.height
                width: taskColumn.height
                color: "transparent"
                Rectangle
                {
                    id: rect22
                    color: "green"
                    width: parent.width - 20
                    height: parent.height - 20
                    radius: 15
                    border.color: "lightsteelblue"
                    border.width: 1

                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
            }
            Column
            {
                id: taskColumn
                width: listView1.width - editButton.width - dificultStatus.width - 10
                Row
                {
                    Text
                    {
                        text: task_subject
                        color: "lightsteelblue"
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        font {family: localFont.name; pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1}
                    }
                    Text
                    {
                        text: task_subject
                        color: "lightsteelblue"
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        font {family: localFont.name; pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1}
                    }
                }
                Text
                {
                    id: text1
                    height: 50
                    width: parent.width
                    clip: true
                    text: task_body

                    color: "lightsteelblue"
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                    font {family: localFont.name; pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1}
                }
            }
            Button
            {
                id: editButton
                height: taskColumn.height
                width: taskColumn.height
                background:
                Rectangle
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "transparent"
                    Rectangle
                    {
                        color: "transparent"
                        width: parent.width - 20
                        height: parent.height - 20
                        radius: 15
                        border.color: "lightsteelblue"
                        border.width: 1

                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: qsTr("...")
                    color: "lightsteelblue"
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    font.pixelSize: 24
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
                onClicked:
                {
                    listView1.currentIndex = index
                    gIdd = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_idd
                    gSubject = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_subject
                    gBody = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_body
                    listView1.currentIndex = index
                    stackView.push("page3.qml")
                }
            }




            /*
             *
             *
             * AddButton Component
             *
             *
             */
            Button
            {
                height: taskColumn.height
                width: taskColumn.height
                x: 0
                y: 80
                visible: setVisibility()
                //visible: (myModel.rowCount() === ++myIndex) ?  true : false
                background:
                Rectangle
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "transparent"
                    Rectangle
                    {
                        color: "transparent"
                        width: parent.width - 20
                        height: parent.height - 20
                        radius: 15
                        border.color: "lightsteelblue"
                        border.width: 1

                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: qsTr("+")
                    color: "lightsteelblue"
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    font.pixelSize: 24
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
                onClicked:
                {
                    listView1.currentIndex = index
                    gIdd = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_idd
                    gSubject = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_subject
                    gBody = listView1.currentItem.mainData.task_body
                    listView1.currentIndex = index
                    stackView.push("page2.qml")
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `ListView`'s [`footer` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#footer-prop). The default [`footerPositioning`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#footerPositioning-prop) is what you want.